# Accessing props in constructor vuejs

Tags: vue.js, constructor

I'm looking for accessing props from constructor in VueJS.

I tried the react way like you can see below but without any success at that time.

Parent :

```
<nb-add-card
 test="test props">
</nb-add-card>
```

Child:

```
<template>
 <div>
  test : {{ test }}
 </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';

@Component({
 components: { },
 props: {
  test: {
   type: String,
   default: "",
   required: true
  },
 },
})
export default class AddCard extends Vue {
 constructor(props: any) {
  super(props);
  console.log('TEST :', props); // => Undefined
  console.log('TEST1 :', this); // => Refer to AddCard
 }
}
</script>
```

The log "TEST" still "undefined".
Being stuck on this for hours now, on react we just simply pass "props" in constructor args, but in vuejs, it's seems not working... :/

I also test to access the props value by writing the props name of **< nb-add-card >** but it's not working either...

```
 constructor(test: any) {
  super(test);
  console.log('TEST :', test); // => Undefined
  console.log('TEST1 :', this); // => Refer to AddCard
 }
```

Anyone have an idea ? Thank's

Comment: Maybe you should look at the [created](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) lifecycle hook?

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is of no use with vue-class-component. What you're exporting is a constructor itself. Your 'test' var is immediately accesable within' the component. Use the 'created' or 'mounted' hook to log it.